# UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR required or not?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

For below code to work we should generally define a aFont property in TestView.h with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. But, it seems it is not required. I tried with and without the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR, results are the same.

I don't know if this is right or wrong?

> [[TestView appearance] setAFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestView.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     [[TestView appearance] setAFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**TestView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIView
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIFont *aFont  ;
@end
```

**TestView.m**

```
#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestView
{
    UILabel *aTestLabel;
}
@synthesize aFont=_aFont;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    NSLog(@"A Font= %@ ",_aFont);
}


-(id) init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        [self addLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [self addLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addLabel{
    aTestLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    aTestLabel.text=@"Hello";
    _aFont=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];

    [self addSubview:aTestLabel];
}

-(void)setAFont:(UIFont *)aFont{
    _aFont=aFont;
    aTestLabel.font=_aFont;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the UIAppearance protocol unless you want to control a subview of a view you haven't coded yourself, or you want to control an appearance system wide. It's not needed here. Just set the font directly.

In TestView.m do something like this:

```
- (void)setAFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    _aFont = font;
    self.aTestLabel.font = _aFont;
}
```

Comment: I am controlling it system wide, I have two views in IB, with subclass to TestView. I set the TestView appearance in application:didFinisihLaunching

Comment: But you're still able to just set the values directly since it's your class. UIAppearance isn't needed here. Use UIAppearance to do things like set the font in all of the applications's UINavigationBars, which is a UIKit class you don't have direct access to modify.

Comment: So, If subclass UINavigationBar(TestNavigationBar.h) and define a new property of font with the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. How that case will be different from the one which I explained above.(It is a subclass of UIView) Can you please explain with a code snippet?

Comment: My example used UINavigationBar, it didn't subclass it. In your example, you added the UILabel to the view, so you have full access to it Just set the font you want. Don't make it more complex than it needs to be.